# JPA 2 one-to-one fetch=FetchType.EAGER not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

In my UserTbl entity, I have this

```
@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
private RetailPostUserTbl retailPostUser;

@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
private BackOfficeUserTbl backOfficeUser;
```

But both are ALWAYS null.

A user must belong to at least one of them or both but the query always return null.

I tried fetching it via the criteria api like this

```
    Root<UserTbl> root = cq.from( UserTbl.class );
    root.fetch( UserTbl_.retailPostUser, JoinType.LEFT );
    root.fetch( UserTbl_.backOfficeUser, JoinType.LEFT );
```

But they are still always null.

Any ideas why this is not working?

The reverse works fine, for eg

in RetailPostUserTbl, this works

```
@OneToOne( optional = false, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE )
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private UserTbl user;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong while saving or retrieving the entity, for @OneToOne mapping the FetchType is by default EAGER and you don't have to mention it explicitly.
Have you tried to load the entity by -

```
entityManager.find();
```

if above method works and returns the entity with all the mapped objects then check your criteria query.

Comment: That also returns null and that is why i added the FetchType.EAGER , the reverse works, see the new edits

Comment: I was doing things wrong! Because it was loading the objects when the actual data was requested and i was making my asserts before that actually happen by introspection.